# Float left not working in mobile devices like ipod, android smartphones

Tags: html, css, ipod, smartphone

Floating left 'li' not working in ipod, android devices. But it works perfect in all major broswers in laptop / destops. Code is here:

```
<ul class="clsvideos clearfix">
<li>
    <div class="home-thumb">
        <div class="home-play-container">
            <div class="play-button-hover">
                <div class="movie-entry yt-uix-hovercard">
                    <div class="tooltip">
                        <a href="/index.php/component/deentube/player/Education-Travel/Abdul-Basit-reciting-Surah-Infitar" class="info_hover"><img class="yt-uix-hovercard-target" src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/pF6Yq7DrJKA/1.jpg" border="0" width="140" height="83" title=""> </a>
                        <div class="Tooltipwindow clearfix">
                            <img src="http://video.muslimbackyard.com/templates/videoplus/images/tip.png" class="tipimage">
                            <div class="clearfix"><span class="clstoolleft">Category : </span><span class="clstoolright">Education &amp; Travel</span></div>

                            <span class="clsdescription">Description : </span><p>Abdul Basit reciting Surah Infitar - amazing tajweed! mash'Allah!</p><div class="clearfix"> <span class="clstoolleft">Rating : </span>                                                                    <div class="clstoolright ratingvalue ratethis1 fivepos1"></div>                                                            
                                <div class="clearfix"><span class="clstoolleft"> Views:</span>                                                                        <span class="clstoolright">58                                                                        </span></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="show-title-container">
                <a href="/index.php/component/deentube/player/Education-Travel/Abdul-Basit-reciting-Surah-Infitar" class="show-title-gray info_hover">Abdul Basit reciting Surah Infitar </a>
            </div>
            <span class="video-info">  <a href="/index.php/component/deentube/category/Education-Travel">Education &amp; Travel                                                                    </a> </span>
            <div class="video-info clearfix">
                <div class="clsratingvalue"><span class="ratethis1 fivepos1 "></span></div>
                <div class="clsvideosviews">58 Views</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div></li>
<li>
    <div class="home-thumb">
        <div class="home-play-container">
            <div class="play-button-hover">
                <div class="movie-entry yt-uix-hovercard">
                    <div class="tooltip">
                        <a href="/index.php/component/deentube/player/Sports-Gaming/How-the-Bible-Led-Me-to-Islam-The-Story-of-a-Former-Christian-Youth-Minister-Joshua-Evans" class="info_hover"><img class="yt-uix-hovercard-target" src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/IYMKQKSV0bY/1.jpg" border="0" width="140" height="83" title=""> </a>
                        <div class="Tooltipwindow clearfix">
                            <img src="http://video.muslimbackyard.com/templates/videoplus/images/tip.png" class="tipimage">
                            <div class="clearfix"><span class="clstoolleft">Category : </span><span class="clstoolright">Sports &amp; Gaming</span></div>
                            <span class="clsdescription">Description : </span><p>How the Bible Led Me to Islam: The Story of a Former Christian Youth Minister - Joshua Evans</p><div class="clearfix"> <span class="clstoolleft">Rating : </span>                                                                    <div class="clstoolright ratingvalue ratethis1 fourpos1"></div>                                                            
                                <div class="clearfix"><span class="clstoolleft"> Views:</span>                                                                        <span class="clstoolright">41                                                                        </span></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="show-title-container">
                <a href="/index.php/component/deentube/player/Sports-Gaming/How-the-Bible-Led-Me-to-Islam-The-Story-of-a-Former-Christian-Youth-Minister-Joshua-Evans" class="show-title-gray info_hover">How the Bible Led Me to Islam: The ... </a>
            </div>
            <span class="video-info">  <a href="/index.php/component/deentube/category/Sports-Gaming">Sports &amp; Gaming                                                                    </a> </span>
            <div class="video-info clearfix">
                <div class="clsratingvalue"><span class="ratethis1 fourpos1 "></span></div>
                <div class="clsvideosviews">41 Views</div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div></li>
```

Corresponding CSS is:

```
.clsvideos li:first-child {
width: 140px;
float: left;
padding: 14px 10px 0 0;
display: block;
}
.clsvideos li {
height: 155px;
width: 140px;
padding: 14px 10px 0 9px;
border-right: 1px dotted #CFCFCF;
border-bottom: 1px dotted #CFCFCF;
float: left;
}
```

Live URL: http://video.muslimbackyard.com/

Note: Open the site in a smartphone and destop. Note the disign issues at Popular Videos, Recent Videos section. You will know where the problem exists.

Awaiting for a solution at the earliest

Comment: It looks fine on my LG P500... https://www.dropbox.com/s/tx6jcj27v6t36kv/2012-11-02%2012.31.06.png

Comment: Also, you're duplicating some CSS rules. The `width` and `float` rules only need to be declared in the `.clsvideos li` selector.

Comment: Thanks @decastro.

Actually the problem was, the developer hadn't closed the last 'div' inside 'li' which led to this bug...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem was, the developer hadn't closed the last 'div' inside 'li' which led to this bug...

"So be careful with front-end code while writing core php". This is what the advise I have to my developer.